# is there a way in Timber to show parent method name in the logs android

Tags: android, kotlin, timber-android

I know that I can show the method names in Timber and even the line number using something like that

```kotlin
  class MyDebugTree : DebugTree() {

        override fun createStackElementTag(element: StackTraceElement): String? {
            return String.format(
                " [M:%s] [C:%s]",
                element.methodName,
                super.createStackElementTag(element)
            )
        }
    }
```

but what I want to do is not only to show the method name containing the Timber statement but also the parent method.
Example: I want to show the name of method **a**

```kotlin
 fun a(){
   b()
}
fun b(){
 Timber.d("statement")
}
```

Comment: hi bro, have you found the solution ? I have the same question like yours

Comment: Sadly, no ... I haven't found a way